# How to make iframe fullscreen of the parent document (like youtube)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm the developer of a website that creates maps that are meant to be included on bloggers websites. I'd like to add a feature that allows users to render the map fullscreen.
I read threads about `requestFullscreen` methods (that depends on the browser), but I have to call this method on the iframe element that is not on my website but on bloggers ones.
I tried to call `window.parent.document` to find the `iframe` element and call `requestFullscreen` but it's not possible with Cross domain iframes.

I'm sure this is possible because Youtube does it. I'm not sure if they inject a script that does the job or something.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use html element Allowfullscreen

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe